# Fix bootstrap modal content size for all Tab of in it

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal with 3 tab in it. size of modal content for each one of tabs are different. i want to fix modal content for all tabs. 
what i must do?

my code:

```
<ul id="EditTabs" class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
    <li  class="active">
        <a href="#first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <icon class="fa fa-user" ></icon> مشخصات
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="ImageEditLiTab">
        <a href="#second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> عکس
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LiGoogleMapEditThird">
        <a href="#third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> نقشه
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="first">

        <!--------- end input texts-------------->
        <br>
        <!-- Text input-->

        <div  class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8  inputGroupContainer">
                <div  dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                    <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentFirstName"  name="EditStudentFirstName" placeholder="نام" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="EditStudentFirstName" class="col-md-3 control-label">نام           </label>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->

        <div  class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                    <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentLastName" name="EditStudentLastName" placeholder="نام خانوادگی" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="EditStudentLastName" class="col-md-3 control-label" >نام خانوادگی         </label>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                    <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentAddress" name="EditStudentAddress" placeholder="آدرس" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="EditStudentAddress" class="col-md-3 control-label">آدرس منزل       </label>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div  class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                    <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentZip" name="EditStudentZip" placeholder="کد پستی" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="EditStudentZip" class="col-md-3 control-label">کد پستی   </label>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div  class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                    <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentPhone" name="EditStudentPhone" placeholder=" شماره تلفن منزل" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="EditStudentPhone" class="col-md-3 control-label">شماره تلفن منزل  </label>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div  class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                    <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentMobile" name="EditStudentMobile" placeholder="شماره موبایل" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="EditStudentMobile" class="col-md-3 control-label">شماره موبایل   </label>
        </div>


        <!-- Text input-->
        <div  class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                    <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentUsername" name="EditStudentUsername" placeholder="نام کاربری دانش آموز" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="EditStudentUsername" class="col-md-3 control-label">نام کاربری دانش آموز        </label>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div  class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                    <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentPass" name="EditStudentPass" placeholder="پسورد دانش آموز" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="EditStudentPass" class="col-md-3 control-label">پسورد دانش آموز   </label>
        </div>

        <!--------- end input texts-------------->

    </div><!-- End first Tab-->
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="second" dir="ltr">

        <form id="imagesubmit2" action="http://79.132.212.50:8080/SchoolServiceWebService/user/photo/set" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input id="Adminusername2"  hidden type="textbox" name="username" size="45" />
            <input id="Adminuserpassword2" hidden type="textbox" name="password" size="45" />
            <input id="EditStudentuserid"  hidden  type="textbox" name="userid" size="45" />
            <!--  <input id="file-4" type="file" class="file" size="45" data-upload-url="http://79.132.212.50:8080/SchoolServiceWebService/user/photo/set">-->

           <!--  <input id="file-4" type="file" name="file" size="45" class="file col-md-6 file2" />-->

            <input id="input-24" name="file" type="file" multiple size="45"   class="file-loading col-md-6 file2">

        </form>

    </div><!-- End second Tab-->


    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="third">

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="Updateaddress_with_google">آدرس را بر روی نقشه مشخص کنید</label>

        <div class="span11">
            <div id="UpdateMap"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="Updatebutton_Google_Serach" type="button" class="btn btn-info" >جستجو</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input  type="text" id="Updateaddress_with_google" name="Updateaddress_with_google" placeholder="جستجو" class="form-control" />
            </div>

        </div>

        <input type="text" hidden id="UpdatelatGoogleMap">
        <input type="text" hidden id="UpdatelngGoogleMap">
        <br>
    </div><!-- End third Tab-->

</div>
```

size of first tab:
[image]
size of second tab:
[image]

Comment: Make a jsfiddle or snippet...

Comment: You are using `col-md-8` in the first tab, but you are not using any `col` in the second, so the padding from boostrap dont apply

Comment: try using .custom-class-assignedto-modal .modal-dialog {width: 90%;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See I have updated my Code now it will work as you want.

Checkout code given below this may solve your problem.
and if you want to change width of modal based on width of screen use `@media` query provided by `CSS`

```css
.custom-class-assignedto-modal .modal-dialog {
  width: 50%;
}
.custom-class-assignedto-modal .modal-body {
  height: 400px;
  overflow : auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade custom-class-assignedto-modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" align="center">
      <div class="modal-dialog" align="left">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            <ul id="EditTabs" class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                  <icon class="fa fa-user"></icon>مشخصات
                </a>
              </li>
              <li id="ImageEditLiTab">
                <a href="#second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                  <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> عکس
                </a>
              </li>
              <li id="LiGoogleMapEditThird">
                <a href="#third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> نقشه
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="first">

                <!--------- end input texts-------------->
                <br>
                <!-- Text input-->

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8  inputGroupContainer">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                      <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentFirstName" name="EditStudentFirstName" placeholder="نام" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <label for="EditStudentFirstName" class="col-md-3 control-label">نام</label>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                      <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentLastName" name="EditStudentLastName" placeholder="نام خانوادگی" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <label for="EditStudentLastName" class="col-md-3 control-label">نام خانوادگی</label>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                      <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentAddress" name="EditStudentAddress" placeholder="آدرس" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <label for="EditStudentAddress" class="col-md-3 control-label">آدرس منزل</label>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                      <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentZip" name="EditStudentZip" placeholder="کد پستی" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <label for="EditStudentZip" class="col-md-3 control-label">کد پستی</label>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                      <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentPhone" name="EditStudentPhone" placeholder=" شماره تلفن منزل" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <label for="EditStudentPhone" class="col-md-3 control-label">شماره تلفن منزل</label>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                      <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentMobile" name="EditStudentMobile" placeholder="شماره موبایل" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <label for="EditStudentMobile" class="col-md-3 control-label">شماره موبایل</label>
                </div>


                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                      <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentUsername" name="EditStudentUsername" placeholder="نام کاربری دانش آموز" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <label for="EditStudentUsername" class="col-md-3 control-label">نام کاربری دانش آموز</label>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="input-group">
                      <input dir="rtl" id="EditStudentPass" name="EditStudentPass" placeholder="پسورد دانش آموز" class="form-control" type="text">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <label for="EditStudentPass" class="col-md-3 control-label">پسورد دانش آموز</label>
                </div>

                <!--------- end input texts-------------->

              </div>
              <!-- End first Tab-->
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="second" dir="ltr">

                <form id="imagesubmit2" action="http://79.132.212.50:8080/SchoolServiceWebService/user/photo/set" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                  <input id="Adminusername2" hidden type="textbox" name="username" size="45" />
                  <input id="Adminuserpassword2" hidden type="textbox" name="password" size="45" />
                  <input id="EditStudentuserid" hidden type="textbox" name="userid" size="45" />
                  <!--  <input id="file-4" type="file" class="file" size="45" data-upload-url="http://79.132.212.50:8080/SchoolServiceWebService/user/photo/set">-->

                  <!--  <input id="file-4" type="file" name="file" size="45" class="file col-md-6 file2" />-->

                  <input id="input-24" name="file" type="file" multiple size="45" class="file-loading col-md-6 file2">

                </form>

              </div>
              <!-- End second Tab-->


              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="third">

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="Updateaddress_with_google">آدرس را بر روی نقشه مشخص کنید</label>

                <div class="span11">
                  <div id="UpdateMap"></div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="Updatebutton_Google_Serach" type="button" class="btn btn-info">جستجو</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" id="Updateaddress_with_google" name="Updateaddress_with_google" placeholder="جستجو" class="form-control" />
                  </div>

                </div>

                <input type="text" hidden id="UpdatelatGoogleMap">
                <input type="text" hidden id="UpdatelngGoogleMap">
                <br>
              </div>
              <!-- End third Tab-->

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>




</body>

</html>
```